# Optimizing a Cypher query to improve performance

Tags: neo4j, cypher

The query I've written returns accurate results based on  some random testing I've done. However, the query execution takes really long (7699.43 s) 
I need help optimising this query.

count(Person) -> 67895

count(has_POA) -> 355479

count(POADocument) -> 40

count(issued_by) -> 40

count(Company) -> 21

count(PostCode) -> 9845

count(Town) -> 1673

count(in_town) -> 9845

count(offers_services_in) -> 17107

All the entity nodes are indexed on Id's (not Neo4j IDs). The PostCode nodes are also indexed on PostCode.

[image]
[image]

```
MATCH pa= (p:Person)-[r:has_POA]->(d:POADocument)-[:issued_by]->(c:Company),
(pc:PostCode),(t:Town) WHERE r.recipient_postcode=pc.PostCode AND (pc)-
[:in_town]->(t) AND NOT (c)-[:offers_services_in]->(t) RETURN p as Person,r 
as hasPOA,t as Town, d as POA,c as Company
```

Much thanks in advance!
-Nancy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified version of your current query.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_POA]->(d:POADocument)-[:issued_by]->(c:Company)
MATCH (t:Town)<-[:in_town]-(pc:PostCode{PostCode:r.recipient_postcode})
WHERE NOT (c)-[:offers_services_in]->(t)
RETURN p as Person,r as hasPOA,t as Town, d as POA,c as Company
```

Your big performance hits are going to be on the Cartesian product between all the match sets, and the raw amount of data you are asking for.

In this simplified version, I'm using one less match, and the second match uses a variable from the first match to avoid generating a Cartesian product. I would also recommend using LIMIT and SKIP to page your results to limit data transfer.

If you can adjust your model, I would recommend converting the has_POA relation to an issued_POA node so that you can take advantage of Neo4j's relation finding on the 2 postcodes related to that instance, and making the second match a gimme instead of an extra indexed search (after you adjust the query to match the new model, of course).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Tezra. I've tried your query and it has brought down the execution time to 30 s!

Comment: I initially had the two attributes i currently have on has_POA relation (issued_date & recipient_postcode) as part of the POADocument itself. But i read somewhere that entities shouldn't have transactional attributes, so i moved the attributes to the relation instead. You're asking me to move the two attributes to a new node/entity. If i did that and changed my query, i would still have to match the postcodes on the new node and the PostCode node, correct?

Comment: @Nancy The match would become something like `MATCH (p:Person)-[:has_POA]->(i:issued_POA)-[r:has_POA]->(d:POADocument)-[:issued_by]->(c:Company)
 MATCH (t:Town)<-[:in_town]-(pc:PostCode)<-[:recipient_postcode]-(i)`. So getting the PostCode node would just be an expansion of the node from the first match, instead of an index search using a variable from the first match. In Neo4j, if you put a foreign key (node ID) in a relationship property, that relationship should probably be a node. Neo4j's strength is relationships, not tables.

Comment: I would also recommend making nodes resemble their actual objects as closely as possible. The less you have to think about it, the easier it is to work with (generally)

Comment: I did as you suggested, so my query looks like this now: 
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:registered]->(a:POA)-[:doc_type]->(d:POADocument)-[:issued_by]->(c:Company)
MATCH (t:Town)<-[:in_town]-(pc)<-[:registered_postcode]-(a)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:offers_services_in]->(t) 
RETURN p as Person,a as POA,t.TownId as TownId, d as DocType, c.Id as CompanyId limit 10


But its not changed the query execution time much. Its almost the same. I do get what you're saying about moving foreign key attributes to nodes.

Answer (score 3):

I made some changes in your query:

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r:has_POA {recipient_code : {code} }]->(d:POADocument)-[:issued_by]->(c:Company),
    (pc:PostCode {PostCode : {PostCode} })-[:in_town]->(t:Town)
WHERE NOT (c)-[:offers_services_in]->(t)
    RETURN p as Person, r as hasPOA, t as Town, d as POA, c as Company
```

1. Since you are not using the entire path, removed `pa` variable
2. Moved the pattern existence check (`(pc)-[:in_town]->(t)`) from `WHERE` to `MATCH`.
3. Using parameters instead of the equality check `r.recipient_postcode = pc.PostCode` in where. If you are running the query in Neo4j Browser, you can set the parameters running the command `:params {code : 10}`.